# Docker container is killed during performance tests

Tags: docker, dmesg

I need to understand why docker container is being killed during processing.

**Short background:**

we're running performance tests in RH machine. (Machine has 64GB RAM, 16 CPU) after 20 hours of run or so, the container is being killed by the kernel.

We are running java inside container and it's heap is limited to 20GB. (it's a heavy process that indexes files into elasticsearch.)

also we monitor the memory consumption inside the docker with ps- eF and heapsize with Glowroot.

**The Max HeapSize** is 6.7GB, before the process is killed.

**ps -eF** shows that **RSS** is 16977356 (1.7GB)

**dmesg output is:**

```
[Mon Nov 12 08:44:10 2018] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
[Mon Nov 12 08:44:11 2018] [ 3406]     0  3406  7811475  4240564    8512        0             0 java
[Mon Nov 12 08:44:11 2018] Out of memory: Kill process 3406 (java) score 264 or sacrifice child
[Mon Nov 12 08:44:11 2018] Killed process 3406 (java) total-vm:31245900kB, anon-rss:16962256kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

if I understand correctly, **total-vm** represent the RAM used by all processed and **anon-rss** by the process that was killed. that means that my machine should have 25GB of free memory.

Comment: Did you take a look at the behaviour of swap memory usage? Did you set any memory limit for the container?

Comment: The container is not limited not in memory and not in memory usage. when i ran free -h, all the memory swap values were 0

Comment: All memory swap values were 0?  That would indicate that no swap is available on this machine and it would be very touchy with any memory pressure.  Is this a virtual machine or hosted VPS and not real hardware?  If this is a hosted virtual machine, the host owner may have put additional memory constraints on your instance.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory**

Understand the risks of running out of memory

It is important not to allow a running container to consume too much of the host machine’s memory. On Linux hosts, if the kernel detects that there is not enough memory to perform important system functions, it throws an OOME, or Out Of Memory Exception, and starts killing processes to free up memory. Any process is subject to killing, including Docker and other important applications. This can effectively bring the entire system down if the wrong process is killed.

(...)

**Limit a container’s access to memory**

```
-m or --memory= The maximum amount of memory the container can use. If you set this option, the minimum allowed value is 4m (4 megabyte).
```

Sources:

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#memory

Comment: Thanks, I've limited the Java heap size inside the docker. what seems  weird to me is that the machine has enough memory as shown in the dmesg output: total-vm:31245900kB, anon-rss:16962256kB.